# How exactly is the %y directive interpreted when parsing dates?

Tags: python, date, time, strptime

While reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49950741/1222951) about parsing dates of the form `%m/%d/%y`, I realized that I don't know how the `%y` directive actually works.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) state the following:

> Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.

But which century does it use? If I use `%y` to parse the year `01`, will that result in 1901 or 2001? If I re-run the same code in 100 years, will it result in 2101?

---

As an experiment, I wrote some code that parses all numbers from 0 to 99 and displays the results:

```
for year in range(100):
    date = '6/1/{:>02}'.format(year)
    dt = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%y")
    print(year, dt.date())
```

The results were surprising:

```
0 2000-06-01
1 2001-06-01
2 2002-06-01
...
67 2067-06-01
68 2068-06-01
69 1969-06-01 # <- wut
70 1970-06-01
71 1971-06-01
...
98 1998-06-01
99 1999-06-01
```

Why does it suddenly jump from 2068 to 1969? Is this behavior documented anywhere? What's the formal specification for `%y`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) docs, emphasis mine:

> **Year 2000 (Y2K) issues**: Python depends on the platform’s C library, which generally doesn’t have year 2000 issues, since all dates and times are represented internally as seconds since the epoch. Function `strptime()` can parse 2-digit years when given `%y` format code. **When 2-digit years are parsed, they are converted according to the POSIX and ISO C standards: values 69–99 are mapped to 1969–1999, and values 0–68 are mapped to 2000–2068.**

Answer (score 1):

You can read the CPython implementation of strptime [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_strptime.py), and in particular at lines [384-392](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61f82e0e337f971da57f8f513abfe693edf95aa5/Lib/_strptime.py#L384) there is the interesting bit:

```
    if group_key == 'y':
        year = int(found_dict['y'])
        # Open Group specification for strptime() states that a %y
        #value in the range of [00, 68] is in the century 2000, while
        #[69,99] is in the century 1900
        if year <= 68:
            year += 2000
        else:
            year += 1900
```

This behavior is also explained in the manual ot [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html):

> Year 2000 (Y2K) issues: Python depends on the platform’s C library, which generally doesn’t have year 2000 issues, since all dates and times are represented internally as seconds since the epoch. Function strptime() can parse 2-digit years when given %y format code. When 2-digit years are parsed, they are converted according to the POSIX and ISO C standards: **values 69–99 are mapped to 1969–1999, and values 0–68 are mapped to 2000–2068**.

Comment: Looks like `Year 2068 problem`... I wonder how many little `Year 20xx` problems we have around that everyone forgot about. "It's patched, but we need to fix it before year 20xx" -- "That's plenty of time. Create a low priority ticket"

Answer (score 0):

`strptime` presumably is a basic wrapper around C's `strptime`.

Of `strptime`, [the POSIX specification states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html):

> `%y` The year within century. When a century is not otherwise specified, values in the range [69,99] shall refer to years 1969 to 1999 inclusive, and values in the range [00,68] shall refer to years 2000 to 2068 inclusive; leading zeros shall be permitted but shall not be required.
>
> Note: It is expected that in a future version of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will change. (This would apply to all commands accepting a 2-digit year as input.)